# Replacing center cards in Ascension

Tags: ascension

Do I understand the rules correctly in that all center cards are replaced when defeated/bought?

So I can if I have good power cards spend some runes on replacing cheap cards in order to hope something stronger with a better reward will come up to replace them cards, or is the turn played with the cards at the center and then replaced when your turn finishes?

The rules as I read them seems to suggest that they are replaced when fought/bought but that made the game feel very strange. This might simply be a feeling based on playing a lot of Dominion lately with its restrictions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have only played one game of Ascension, and I got the same idea.

Here is the ruling directly from the download-able [FAQ](http://www.ascensiongame.com/download/rules/ascension_faq.pdf):

> Q:  When does a card in the center row get replaced?  If I defeat Mephit, do I banish a card 
>   in the center row before or after a new card replaces the Mephit?
>
> A:  Whenever a card leaves the center row, **the first thing that happens is that it is replaced from the center deck**.  There should be six cards in the center row at all times.  In this instance, if you 
>   defeat Mephit, you replace the Mephit from the center deck and then make your decision about 
>   what card to banish.

[FAQ Link](http://www.ascensiongame.com/download/rules/ascension_faq.pdf)